# Accessing files inside the folder, which is inside config folder in sails js(node js framework)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have to access a file , which is inside a folder which is inside the `config` folder(`/config/schemas/userSchemas.js`). How to access this file from anywhere else like from my controllers or services. How to do this?
I have tried `sails.config.schemas.userSchemas`. But it didn't work. What else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not recommended that you `require` configuration files directly. Sails will require them for you, and merge the contents into `sails.config`, ignoring your directory structure completely.  So if, for example, your `config/schemas/userSchemas.js` file contains:

```
module.exports.userSchemas = {
   foo: "bar"
}
```

Then you'll be able to access that config in your app as `sails.config.userSchemas`.  **Note the first line very carefully**:  if you just do `module.exports = {...}` then the object will be merged into `sails.config`, *not* `sails.config.userSchemas` -- as I said before, configuration is merged in without regard to directory structure.

If you have files that you need to load in which you *don't* want to be part of `sails.config`, simply place them in a different folder in your project (e.g. `schemas`) and use `require` as specified in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have following directory structure

```
myapp
├── app.js
├── _config
│   ├── _schemas
|       |
|       ├── userSchemas.js
|       ├── otherSchemas.js
|
├── _controller
│   ├── _module1
|   |   |
|   |   ├── userController.js
|   |   ├── otherController.js
|   ├── otherController.js
```

In `app.js`, you may access as

```
require('./config/schemas/userSchemas.js');
```

In `otherController.js`, you may access as

```
require('../config/schemas/userSchemas.js');
```

In `userController.js`, you may access as

```
require('../../config/schemas/userSchemas.js');
```

Conclude: **`..`** is used to go to parent directory(one directory back) while **`.`** is used for current directory

I hope this will help you directory structure in node.js

Comment: This is a fine answer for Node in general, but not really appropriate for Sails config files, which are not meant to be `require`d directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to define a global variable for path.

Consider you have following directory structure (as mentioned in @arif's answer).

```
myapp
├── app.js
├── _config
│   ├── _schemas
|       |
|       ├── userSchemas.js
|       ├── otherSchemas.js
|
├── _controller
│   ├── _module1
|   |   |
|   |   ├── userController.js
|   |   ├── otherController.js
|   ├── otherController.js
```

Now in you app.js write the first line as follow.

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/';
```

**Note** : now global.__base points to `/path-to-your-myapp-directory/myapp/`

Now you can access `userSchema.js` or any other file like this.

In all the files (`app.js`, `otherController.js`, `userController.js`), you can require `userSchemas.js` like this

```
require(global.__base + 'config/schemas/userSchemas.js');
```

Comment: Sails already provides a reference to the app path in `sails.config.appPath`, and to the config directory in `sails.config.paths.config`.

Comment: @sgress454 I have no experience in sails, I have answered it based on nodejs